# Remote Program (via ssh) suspends when leaving client computer

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm working with MATLAB on a remote computer logging in via `ssh -X remotepc`
and running matlab like `matlab &`.

When I start a long-running process and leave the computer, it seems to suspend the process (after like 30mins being away) such that there is nearly no progress over night.

As soon as I come back and wake up the client, the remote process continues with the calculation. I can see this from the load-average values (`uptime`)

Why is that and how can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options that look helpful in `man ssh_config`:

`TCPKeepAlive` – this should be `yes` on default, if it isn't on your machine try `ssh -X -o TCPKeepAlive=yes remotepc`.

`ServerAliveInterval` – use it like `ssh -X -o ServerAliveInterval=30 remotepc` to make ssh send a "keepalive" packet every 30 seconds.

Apart from `man ssh_config` I found [this reference](http://pthree.org/2008/04/16/keeping-your-ssh-connection-alive/).

Comment: Ok, I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Your description suggests to me that the remote machine is hibernating/suspending after a period of being idle (with respect to user input). You should check the power settings on that machine and adjust them to either disable hibernation/suspension or at least lengthen the idle time.

Comment: Hi. I'm pretty sure it doesn't, since it's a linux server that runs 24/7. I'm not the only one who uses it.